# How to find count of repeated ids and also display different ids using sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to find count of repeated  country names and also display different country names using  single sql query?

I have table Source_country_Table

```
INDIA
SPAIN
JAPAN
INDIA
US
UK
US
SPAIN
JAPAN
INDIA
```

Comment: for repeated ids use froup by clause.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to get the count of multiple country names

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(*) FROM Source_country_Table
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Make clear of the second requirement to help you out

Answer (score 0):

```
Select <ID>, count(<ID>) from <TABLE> group by <ID>
```

Probably this should help you. 
Just group by serched column and count it.

Answer (score 0):

To show repeated country names with count:

```
    SELECT Country_Name, COUNT(Country_Name) as Counts FROM 
[Source_country_Table] GROUP BY Country_Name HAVING COUNT(Country_Name) > 1
```

To show all the country names with count:

```
SELECT Country_Name, COUNT(Country_Name) FROM [Source_country_Table] GROUP BY Country_Name
```